# How to force CMake to use a response file when linking CUDA on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, cuda, linker

How to force CMake to use a response file when linking CUDA on Windows?

I have been trying to create a convenience library on Windows in a
project that has CUDA.  The goal is to wrap up several libraries into
one.  The first approach was the straightforward

```
  add_library(conv
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:a>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:b>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:c>
    )
```

which tries to link with nvcc, but overruns the windows command line length limit.  I.e, it emits

```
The command line is too long.
```

There are no problems on Darwin or Linux.

Then I discovered in cmake-3.20.3 the code,

```
  NVIDIA-CUDA.cmake: set(CMAKE_CUDA_RESPONSE_FILE_FLAG "--options-file ")
```

which led me to wonder whether I could just override the defaults by
setting

```
  set(CMAKE_CUDA_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_LIBRARIES TRUE)
```

but upon doing so, I saw no change in behavior.  It still links with nvcc, it still does not use a response file, and it still results in command line too long.

So then I tried setting the linker to be the Windows linker with

```
  set_property(TARGET conv PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

and making sure to have

```
--   CMAKE_CXX_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_LIBRARIES= TRUE
```

But the linker remained nvcc, and no response file was used.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the option to use a response or options file in CUDA is not yet available in CMake. In [current master](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/NVIDIA-CUDA.cmake) (line 129):

```
# FIXME: investigate use of --options-file.
# Tell Makefile generator that nvcc does not support @<rspfile> syntax.
set(CMAKE_CUDA_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_INCLUDES 0)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_LIBRARIES 0)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_OBJECTS 0)
```